Input type (double) and bias type (float) should be the same
I want to train a CNN for reconstructing an image and got the code from someone else (and it worked though it may have been an older release of python for them) but I keep receiving this error.
    from skimage.data import brain
    from skimage.transform import resize, rescale

    import numpy as np
    import torch, torch.nn as nn
    import cv2

    def cv2disp(win, ima, xp, yp, sc): cv2.imshow(win, rescale(ima, sc, False) *1.0/(np.max(ima)+1e-15)); cv2.moveWindow(win, xp, yp)
    def np_to_00torch(np_array):   return torch.from_numpy(np_array).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)
    def torch_to_np(torch_array):  return np.squeeze(torch_array.detach().cpu().numpy())
    device  = torch.device("cuda:o" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"); print(device)

    nxd = 128; disp_scale = 3
    nrd = int(nxd * 1.42); nphi = int(nxd*1.42)

    brainimage=brain()
    true_object_np      = resize(brainimage[9,30:-1, :-30], (nxd,nxd), anti_aliasing=False)
    true_object_torch   = np_to_00torch(true_object_np).to(device)


    cv2disp("True", true_object_np, 0, 0, disp_scale)



    #--------------------------------------Torch System Matrix----------------------------------------------
    def make_torch_system_matrix(nxd, nrd, nphi):
        system_matrix = torch.zeros(nrd*nphi, nxd*nxd) # rows = num sino bins, cols = num image pixels
        for xv in range(nxd):
            for yv in range(nxd):
                for ph in range(nphi):
                yp = -(xv-(nxd*0.5)) * np.sin(ph*np.pi/nphi)+(yv-(nxd*0.5)) * np.cos(ph*np.pi/nphi)
                yp_bin=int(yp+nrd/2)
                system_matrix[yp_bin + ph*nrd, xv + yv*nxd] = 1.0
    return system_matrix


    def fp_system_torch(image, sys_mat, nxd, nrd, nphi):
        fp =  torch.reshape(image, (nxd*nxd,1))
        fb = torch.mm(sys_mat, fp)
        return torch.reshape(fb, (nphi, nrd))
    def bp_system_torch(sino, sys_mat, nxd, nrd, nphi):
           return torch.reshape(torch.mm(sys_mat.T, torch.reshape(sino, (nrd*nphi,1))), (nxd,nxd))



    sys_mat  = make_torch_system_matrix(nxd, nrd, nphi).to(device)
    sys_mat = sys_mat.to(torch.float64)


    true_sinogram_torch  = fp_system_torch(true_object_torch, sys_mat, nxd, nrd, nphi)


    cv2disp("Sinogram", torch_to_np(true_sinogram_torch), disp_scale*nxd, 0, disp_scale)

    #------------------------------------------End FP---------------------------------------------------


    #######################################CNN##########################################################

    class CNN(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, num_channels):
            super(CNN, self).__init__()
            self.CNN = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(1, num_channels, 3, padding=(1, 1), padding_mode='reflect'), nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Conv2d(num_channels, num_channels, 3, padding=(1, 1), padding_mode='reflect'), nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Conv2d(num_channels, num_channels, 3, padding=(1, 1), padding_mode='reflect'), nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Conv2d(num_channels, num_channels, 3, padding=(1, 1), padding_mode='reflect'), nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Conv2d(num_channels, num_channels, 3, padding=(1, 1), padding_mode='reflect'), nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Conv2d(num_channels, num_channels, 3, padding=(1, 1), padding_mode='reflect'), nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Conv2d(num_channels, num_channels, 3, padding=(1, 1), padding_mode='reflect'), nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Conv2d(num_channels, num_channels, 3, padding=(1, 1), padding_mode='reflect'), nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Conv2d(num_channels, 1, 3, padding=(1, 1), padding_mode='reflect'), nn.PReLU(),
        )
        def forward(self,x):
            x = torch.squeeze(self.CNN(x.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)))
                return x

    cnn = CNN(32).to(device)

    #######################################################################################################################


    #-------------------------------------------FBP------------------------------------------------------------------------

    class FBP_CNN_Net(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, cnn, sino_for_reconstruction):
            super(FBP_CNN_Net, self).__init__()
            self.sino_ones = torch.ones_like(sino_for_reconstruction)
            self.sens_image = bp_system_torch(self.sino_ones, sys_mat, nxd, nrd, nphi)
            self.cnn = cnn
            self.prelu = nn.PReLU()

        def forward(self, sino_for_reconstruction):
            filtered_sino = self.cnn(sino_for_reconstruction)
            recon = bp_system_torch(filtered_sino, sys_mat, nxd, nrd, nphi) / (self.sens_image+1.0e-15)
            recon = self.prelu(recon)
            fpsino = fp_system_torch(recon, sys_mat, nxd, nrd, nphi)


            cv2disp("Filtered Sino", torch_to_np(filtered_sino), disp_scale*(nxd+nrd), 0, disp_scale)
            cv2disp("FBP", torch_to_np(recon), disp_scale*(nxd+nrd), disp_scale*nphi+30, disp_scale)
            cv2disp("FP Sino", torch_to_np(fpsino), disp_scale*(nxd+nrd+nphi), 0, disp_scale)
            cv2disp("Difference", torch_to_np(fpsino - sino_for_reconstruction), disp_scale*(nxd+nrd+nrd), disp_scale)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
            return recon, fpsino

    fbpnet = FBP_CNN_Net(cnn, true_sinogram_torch).to(device)

    #===========================================TRAINING OF THE NETWORK

    loss_fun = nn.MSELoss()
    optimiser = torch.optim.Adam(fbpnet.parameters(), lr = 1e-4)

    train_loss = list()
epochs = 60000

    for ep in range(epochs):
        fbp_recon, rec_fp = fbpnet(true_sinogram_torch)
        loss = loss_fun(rec_fp, torch.squeeze(true_sinogram_torch))
        train_loss.append(loss.item())
        loss.backward()
        optimiser.step()
        optimiser.zero_grad()
        print('Epoch %d Training loss = %f' % ( ep, train_loss[-1]))

but the error is telling me RuntimeError: Input type (double) and bias type (float) should be the same.  Does anyone seem to know what this means and how to fix it.  I tried running the code in chunks and the failure happens when I run the for loop at the end to train the network.  I'm not exactly sure what the input is and what the bias is and how to change them (or what to change them to).

Your numpy arrays are of type float64, while your pytorch arrays are of type float32. When you call torch.from_numpy, the numpy datatype is preserved.
Find all the places in the code where you convert a numpy array to a torch tensor and call .float() on the output.
